# Verifying whether a given function can be a norm.

Tags: normed-spaces

I was asked to prove that given the vector space $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$, the function $f(p)=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2$, where $p=(a,b)$, does not define a norm (on $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$).

Is the following argument sufficient:

Take the point $(1,1)$. We have $(-1).(1,1)=(-1,-1)$. We should have $\|(-1).(1,1)\|=|-1|(1,1)=(1,1)$. However, $f(p)=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2$ is not defined for $\|(-1).(1,1)\|$. As a norm function should be defined for every possible scalar in the scalar field (which is $\Bbb{R}$ here), $f(p)=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2$ cannot be a norm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: true but trivial, are you sure that it isn't $(\sqrt{|a|}+\sqrt{|b|})^2$

Comment: Ah you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Also with absolute values this is not a norm, because the triangle inequality is not satisfied. For example,

$$f((1,1))=(1+1)^2=4>2=f((1,0))+f((0,1))$$